# Different thread after await Windows Store App and Windows Phone App...?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, async-await

I am porting a Windows Phone App to Windows 8 and I have problems trouble with async/await. There is a class that needs a while to load all its data. To not block the UI thread the loading is done in a separate task/thread. Once the loading is complete the UI thread needs to be updated:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass() {
      ...
      LoadData();
      ...
   }

   private async void LoadData() {
      Debug.WriteLine("StartLoad: " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
      await ReadDataAsync();
      Debug.WriteLine("EndLoad: " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);

      UpdateUI();
   }

   private Task ReadDataAsync() {
      return Task.Run(() => {
         Debug.WriteLine("Reading: " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
         ...Read...
      });
   }
}
```

On Windows Phone the Output is something like this:

> StartLoad: **1**
>
> Reading: 4
>
> EndLoad: **1**

When I execute the same code in my Windows Store app the output is:

> StartLoad: 1
>
> Reading: **4**
>
> EndLoad: **4**

While on Windows Phone the ThreadId is the same befor and after the await on Windows 8 the ThreadId after the await is NOT the same as before the await. Here it is the same Thread as in the background task. Because of the this UpdateUI() is executed in the wrong (non UI) thread and the app crashes...

What is the reason for this different behaviour?

.
.

**EDIT:**
Well, this is interesting: Although in both cases the process is started from the same thread (3), the problem only shows up when the process is startet from the App() constructor but not when started from OnLaunched. Any idea why this is the case?

```
sealed partial class App : Application {
    public App() {            
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        Debug.WriteLine("App: " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);

        MyClass test = new MyClass();                 
    }

    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnLaunched: " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);

        MyClass test = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

This creates:

> **App: 3**
>
> StartLoad: 3
>
> Reading: 4
>
> EndLoad: **4**
>
> **OnLaunched: 3**
>
> StartLoad: 3
>
> Reading: 5
>
> EndLoad: **3**

Comment: Have you tried `await ReadDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);`

Comment: Thanks, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: There is no need to make your `OnLaunched` method `async` if it is not `await`ing anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were running the code from the thread that would *eventually* start the applications message loop, but it hadn't done so at that point in time.  The `SynchronizationContext` that represents the UI hadn't yet been created and set as the current context.  As such, the `async` method didn't have a context to capture and send the continuations to after each `await`; the default context was used instead, sending the continuations to the thread pool.

You need to run the code later on, once the `SynchronizationContext` has already been set up.  This is why it works when you call it from `OnLaunched`; that runs after the context is set up.

If you look at the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`, you'll see that it's null in your first case, and has a value in the second.  This, rather than checking the current thread's ID, is a much better indicator of whether or not continuations will be able to run in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent explanation! One more question: MyClass has to be initialised as soon as possible since it is accessed from all over the app. I thought App() would be the best place to do this since it is one of the first things being executed. Obviously its is not a good idea. Is OnLaunched the best place for this or are there any other methods that are executed earlier and have everything setup correctly?

Comment: @AndreiHerford Not being a winphone developer, I really couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this is that `LoadData` is not actually being called on the UI thread.

Comment: The constructor of MyClass (and thus LoadData() as well) is called right from the App() methode in the App class. This should be the UI thread, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AndreiHerford Even if it's from the thread that will be used to run the messageloop, if the message loop hasn't started yet then there won't yet be a `SynchronizationContext` representing the UI context for the `async` method to capture.